# VueJS/NuxtJs: How to upload image file and save it to the static folder of nuxtjs project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, laravel-vue

Is it possible the image file must be save in the static folder of nuxtProject? Instead it will save in the backend server using axios. Sorry, I cant gave an example code because i dont have an idea for this. the plan is will save on the static folder and send the frontend url to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

It is may be impossible, because before deploy we build nuxtjs project using "npm run build" command. Then inside project folder we get a new folder name "dist" and the content of "dist" folder we upload our hosting. So, it's a build project we uploaded.

After some day we update some codes, images or others. Then we again build nuxtjs project using "npm run build" and the content of "dist" folder we upload our hosting.

So, I think is not a proper developing way and wrong way.